# Can we use async/await on Express request handlers

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I am doing code cleaning work. I am working on NodeJS, Express REST API. For example I have an API like this:

```js
app.get('/getKeys', isLoggedIn, async(req, res) => {
  var decoded = jwt.decode(res.locals.newToken);
  req.body.profileID = decoded.profileID
  let profileID = decoded.profileID
  req.body.sessionID = req.cookies.sessionID
    .then(async(response) => {
      await pro.sendData(profileID, 'Fetched', {
        profileID,
        keysFetched: true
      })
      console.log(response.data)
      res.cookie('userToken', res.locals.newToken, {
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: 'Strict',
        secure: true,
        domain: 'example.com'
      })
      return res.status(200).send(apiResponse.sendReply(1, 'got KEys', {
        data: response.data.data
      }))
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err.response.data);
      res.cookie('userToken', res.locals.newToken, {
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: 'Strict',
        secure: true,
        domain: 'example.com'
      })
      return res.status(500).send(apiResponse.sendReply(1021, 'redirct to login'))
    })
});
```

For readability and clean code purpose I am trying to use async await instead of promises. I used await on post method, removed await from `pro.sendData`and tried to put everything inside try catch blocks. I dont know whether this is right or wrong. This is my new code.

```js
app.get('/getKeys', isLoggedIn, async(req, res) => {
  try {
    var decoded = jwt.decode(res.locals.newToken);
    req.body.profileID = decoded.profileID
    let profileID = decoded.profileID
    req.body.sessionID = req.cookies.sessionID
    const data = await transport.post(postOffice.SENTRY + '/getKeys', req.body);
    pro.sendData(profileID, 'Fetched', {
      profileID,
      keysFetched: true
    });
    console.log(data);
    res.cookie('userToken', res.locals.newToken, {
      httpOnly: true,
      sameSite: 'Strict',
      secure: true,
      domain: 'example.com'
    });
    return res.status(200).send(apiResponse.sendReply(1, 'got Keys', {
      data: data
    }))
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.data);
    res.cookie('userToken', res.locals.newToken, {
      httpOnly: true,
      sameSite: 'Strict',
      secure: true,
      domain: 'example.com'
    });
    return res.status(500).send(apiResponse.sendReply(1021, 'redirct to login'));
  }
});
```

Comment: definitely you can use it.  you should also put await in-front of decoding the JWT token because you're using that values. 
just a note: do not use var in modern js codes. switch to let / const

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. `async`/`await` is basically just syntactic sugar.

(If you couldn't, your tests would catch this. You have tests, don't you?)

Your "original" code seems to be missing the `const data = await transport.post(postOffice.SENTRY + '/getKeys', req.body);` call, but adding that back in, PyCharm's automatic "convert to async" gives me the following, which is more or less what you have.

```
app.get('/getKeys', isLoggedIn, async (req, res) => {
  const decoded = jwt.decode(res.locals.newToken);
  req.body.profileID = decoded.profileID;
  const profileID = decoded.profileID;
  req.body.sessionID = req.cookies.sessionID;
  try {
    const response = await transport.post(postOffice.SENTRY + '/getKeys', req.body);
    await pro.sendData(profileID, 'Fetched', {
      profileID,
      keysFetched: true,
    });
    console.log(response.data);
    res.cookie('userToken', res.locals.newToken, {
      httpOnly: true,
      sameSite: 'Strict',
      secure: true,
      domain: 'example.com',
    });
    return res.status(200).send(apiResponse.sendReply(1, 'got KEys', {
      data: response.data.data,
    }))
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.response.data);
    res.cookie('userToken', res.locals.newToken, {
      httpOnly: true,
      sameSite: 'Strict',
      secure: true,
      domain: 'example.com',
    });
    return res.status(500).send(apiResponse.sendReply(1021, 'redirct to login'));
  }
});
```